# why no replace() method defined on the Set interface?

Tags: java

Currently I have to write the following to update an element already contained in a Set:

```
Set mySet= ...
Element e1 = new Element (...);
....
....
Element e2 = new Element (...);
\\e1 and e2 are different instances, but equals.

\\update the element contained into the Set
if (mySet.contains(e2)){
    mySet.remove(e2);
    myset.add(e2);
 }
```

That doesnt look nice. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Is the type of `element` such that two instances of the type are "equal" as far as the equal() method is concerned but are not "equal" in some other way that is important to the program?

Comment: the element in the add statement is another than in the contains and remove statement?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: Even if the same instance is used in those three function calls, there could be a different instance that is stored in the set and is "equal to" `element`.  It seems that the OP wants to replace the instance currently in the set with a different, "equal" instance.  I would say that the reason that there is not a method to do what is desired is because that is not the typical--or arguably suggested--use of Set.

Comment: question edited to answer comments above.

Comment: I avoided needing to replace objects altogether by adding the updates to a new set before the old objects. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740040/728602

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A Set is a data structure made to avoid duplicate by mean of using equals() on the object; that also means that two object that are equals() to each other are considered to be perfectly equivalent. Ie, whether you use the version already in the Set or the new one, your code should work the same.

If you want to update the object with a new value, then this is clearly not the case for you (the two version can not replace each other), and you should then use another data structure (eg, a Map, where you can easily override the value, in this case, the key can even be the object itself).

Comment: yes. I realize now that my definition of equals() was too imprecise - leading to some objects being more equals than others ;)

Comment: I don't think that an equals() method gives you an ability to assume two equal objects are perfectly equivalent (certain equiv. relations have to be satisfied but that's about it). And vice versa (that's evident from the default impl. in the Object class). So yes, if two objects are perfectly equivalent then replacing them might not make sense. In other cases, different rules may apply.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is no replace() method defined on the Set interface?

I can think of three reasons:

1. It is functionally redundant: `set.replace(old, nu)` is simply `if (set.remove(old)) { set.add(nu) }` for example.
2. The behavior in the case where `old` is not present adds complications.
3. Adding `replace` to the `Set` API forces all implementations of `Set` to implement a (redundant) method.

It may even be that there are deeper reasons; e.g. to do with the implementability of `replace` in some obscure case.

However, as others have pointed your use case does not require a `replace` at all.  Your code has the same effect (*) as this:

```
    Set myset = ...
    myset.add(element);
```

(* Actually, you might be able to detect a difference if your `element.equals(Object)` method compares element objects field by field.  Depending on the Set implementation, you might get different object references in the sets after executing the two code sequences.  But, IMO you'd be asking for trouble if you made assumptions about that kind of thing!)

Comment: This would be not redundant. For example, some optimization can be added, especially (but not at last) with sorted sets. This method missed not because redundancy, but because "need for replacing" is very uncommon.

Comment: It is *functionally* redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the alternative is just use `add`.

From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29):

> Adds the specified element to this set
>   if it is not already present (optional
>   operation). More formally, adds the
>   specified element e to this set if the
>   set contains no element e2  such that
>   (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
>   If this set already contains the
>   element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

However, I can't really tell from your question if you are trying to *update* or *replace* an element. When you change an element's the property, those changes are automatically reflected in the `Set` because the Set contains references, so no **update** isn't really needed. If your trying to **replace** a *different* element, such a `replace` method would be redundant as explained by [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c).

*(after question edit)*

> e1 and e2 are different instances, but
>   equals.

I suggest that you implement equality on `Element`. That way, the `add` method checks the existence of an element not by reference (the default `Object.equals`) but by your notion of equality on `Element`. So even if the references of e1 and e2 are different, `e1.equals(e2) == true`.

Comment: this doesn't update the old equivalent object with the new object

Comment: Remember that your object needs to be override equals and hashCode for the Set to be able to identify if they are truly the same object.

Comment: @Shervin: That's wrong. The Set API documentation clearly states that equality checks are based on the equals method. Specific Set implementations (e.g. HashSet) may have an additional requirement that hashCode must match as well, but that is not a general requirement for Set usage.

Comment: @jarnbjo: The contract of `hashCode()` requires it to be consistent with `equals()` ( http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29 )and since every class extends `Object` every class is bound to that contract. So your class *must* (almost always) implement `hashCode()` when it implements `equals()`. Whether or not a `Set` implementation *actually depends* on that contract is a different question altogether.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Thanks. I was about to comment @jarnbjo saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No need to remove and then add. Just modify the object directly. Since Sets (or any collection) just store the reference, you don't need a replace() method.</strike>

EDIT : the above statement is INCORRECT. See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

> Note: great care must be exercised if
>   mutable objects are used as map keys.
>   The behavior of a map is not specified
>   if the value of an object is changed
>   in a manner that affects equals
>   comparisons while the object is a key
>   in the map

Comment: Modifying an object that's in a `Set` (especially a `HashSet`) is a dangerous operation. And if the modification changes the results of the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of that object, then it's just plain wrong and is begging for all kinds of bugs.

Comment: @Joachim - Point taken. Here's the official line from javadocs - "Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map"

Answer (score 0):

by definition a set cannot contain an element more than once, so your contains->remove->add thing is pointless.
just add your item as many time as you want to the set.